# Can somebody explain this example code?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

im making a chess game and am having difficulties understanding this code, can someone explain it to me please.

```
def enumerate_moves(x, y):

     potential_moves = [] 

     # If the piece at position (x,y) is a Knight
     if board[x][y] is "Knight":
       potential_moves.append([[x+2], [y+1]])
       potential_moves.append([[x+2], [y-1]])
       potential_moves.append([[x+1], [y+2]])
       potential_moves.append([[x+1], [y-2]])
       potential_moves.append([[x-2], [y-1]])
       potential_moves.append([[x-2], [y+1]])
       potential_moves.append([[x-1], [y+2]])
       potential_moves.append([[x-1], [y-2]])
```

i understand the concept of the code but just dont understand how these ([x-1], [y-2]) are the possible Knight Moves on a 8 by 8  two dimensional array. Can someone please explain how these calculations are made. Thank you!

Comment: The knight can move 2 spaces in one direction, and 1 in the other. These are the enumeration of all of those possible moves.

Comment: looks like this is more a question about chess than python

Comment: FYI, `[x+1], [y+2]` appears twice.

Comment: This code is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Draw out a 5 x 5 grid. Mark the centre square with `x, y`, and pick a direction for `+` and `-` for both `x` and `y`. Look at where the knight can move from the center square and compare that to the offsets in the code here.

Comment: @Robᵩ: yup, one of those two should use `y-2` instead.

Comment: Or use [the Wikipedia diagram for knight moves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight_(chess)#Movement) to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knights can move in the shape of an L. That is up two, over one. Or down two then over one. Actually, you have to account for all L's a knight can make from a given spot. So left, right, up or down two. Then from there the knight can go over (left or right) one. So your options are:

- left 2, then down 1
- left 2, then up 1
- right 2, then up 1
- right 2, then down 1
- up 2, then left 1
- up 2, then right 1
- down 2, then left 1
- down 2, then right 1

Instead of saying up and down, or left after right, we translate up-down to positive and negative `y` respectively and left-right to positive and negative x respectively. That is, in a 2-dimensional cartesian plane (a grid as we know it from algebra class). That being said, the list of options translates to something like the following.

- `[x-2][y+1]`
- `[x-2][y-1]`
- `[x+2][y-1]`
- `[x+2][y+1]`
- `[y-2][y-1]`
- `[y-2][y+1]`
- `[y+2][y-1]`
- `[y+2][y+1]`

So, for one small example. If a knight as at position `[0, 0]`, We have a situation like this:

```
  | 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
__|_________________
0 | K - - - - - - -
1 | - - - - - - - -
2 | - - - - - - - -
3 | - - - - - - - -
4 | - - - - - - - -
5 | - - - - - - - -
6 | - - - - - - - -
7 | - - - - - - - -
```

And, we want to go right 2, down 1 (`[x+2][y+1]`), the outcome would look like:

```
  | 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
__|_________________
0 | - - - - - - - -
1 | - - K - - - - -
2 | - - - - - - - -
3 | - - - - - - - -
4 | - - - - - - - -
5 | - - - - - - - -
6 | - - - - - - - -
7 | - - - - - - - -
```

Comment: No problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

A chess question deserves a chess answer.

Below are the possible moves of a knight on a chess board. We have chosen a central position to maximise the number of possible moves. If the knight were in a corner, it's movements would be restricted.

[image]

If you can imagine the chess board as *x* and *y* coordinates on a graph, the knight can move any combination of [(*x* + (1 or 2)), (*y* + (2 or 1)] positions. You might think this make 2 different moves: [*x*+1, *y*+2], [*x*+2, *y*+1]. But there are 4 potential sign combination of *x* and *y*: -*x*, +*y*; -*x*, -*y*; +*x*, -*y*; -*y*, +*x*, +*x*, +*y*. Therefore, there are 4*2 = 8 possible combinations, as you can see in the diagram above.

As for the code, I will leave that as an exercise.